# LINUX: joining multiples files into 1

Tags: linux

I have 4 files with 1 column each. I want to join them in 1 file. How to do it?

cat file1

```
11122
11123
11124
11125
11126
11127
11128
11129
```

cat file2

```
20427000055328108F
20427000055323101F
20427000055323159F
20427000055321312F
20427000055303027F
20427000055308248F
20427000055326912F
20427000055330368F
```

cat file3

```
0000576000845600
0000576010954200
0000576000089800
0000576010760800
0000869120380200
0000676010234400
0000576010369800
0000869120285700
```

cat file4

```
2013051711440100
2013051711442100
2013051711443600
2013051711444100
2013051711455200
2013051711462600
2013051711464700
2013051711470200
```

output

```
11122   20427000055328108F  0000576000845600    2013051711440100
11123   20427000055323101F  0000576010954200    2013051711442100
11124   20427000055323159F  0000576000089800    2013051711443600
11125   20427000055321312F  0000576010760800    2013051711444100
11126   20427000055303027F  0000869120380200    2013051711455200
11127   20427000055308248F  0000676010234400    2013051711462600
11128   20427000055326912F  0000576010369800    2013051711464700
11129   20427000055330368F  0000869120285700    2013051711470200
```

Comment: This is offtopic on Stack Overflow (no programming involved). You could try, with a bit more info, on http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 15):

Use `paste -> merge lines of files`:

```
paste file1 file2 file2 file3 file4 > output
```

will put each file data in one column.

#### Test

```
$ paste file1 file2 file3 file4 > output
$ 
$ cat output 
11122   20427000055328108F      0000576000845600        2013051711440100
11123   20427000055323101F      0000576010954200        2013051711442100
11124   20427000055323159F      0000576000089800        2013051711443600
11125   20427000055321312F      0000576010760800        2013051711444100
11126   20427000055303027F      0000869120380200        2013051711455200
11127   20427000055308248F      0000676010234400        2013051711462600
11128   20427000055326912F      0000576010369800        2013051711464700
11129   20427000055330368F      0000869120285700        2013051711470200
```